# MatrixError: [400] Adding an email to your account is disabled on this server

Tags: element, matrix-synapse

Could anyone help me with this Matrix Synapse - Element error? I try to allow users to add their email, but I get this error: Unable to add email address
MatrixError: [400] Adding an email to your account is disabled on this server (http://192.*.*.*:****/_matrix/client/r0/account/3pid/email/requestToken)

I already added this inside homeserver.yaml but it still doesn't work: email:
smtp_host: "localhost"
smtp_port: 25
smtp_user: "item.user"
smtp_pass: "Chat.example"
force_tls: true
require_transport_security: true
enable_tls: false
notif_from: "Your friend %(app)s homeserver chat@example.com"
app_name: array
enable_notifs: true
notif_for_new_users: false
client_base_url: "http://localhost/item"
validation_token_lifetime: 15m

Answer (score 0):

You need to set or edit the "3pid change parameter" to true in your `homeserver.yaml` :

```
enable_3pid_changes: true
```

Documentation : https://matrix-org.github.io/synapse/latest/usage/configuration/config_documentation.html#enable_3pid_changes

Comment: Defaults to true.